# Django form QuerySet for ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've got a Form which I'm using the following field in.

```
contact_country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all())
```

The Country model looks like this

```
class Country(models.Model):
    iso = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    printable_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    iso3 = models.CharField(max_length=3,null=True, blank=True)
    numcode = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    special = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):  
        return self.printable_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = [ 'printable_name' ]
```

The 'special' field indicates that the country is "special". If the country is "special" I want it to appear before the rest of the listing - as I'm sure you've seen elsewhere on the web (e.g. English speaking countries like Australia, United Kingdom and United States at the top of the select, but also again with the rest of the countries).

Is that possible with QuerySet? Or should I be looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Does `contact_country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.order_by('special'))` work?

Comment: Yes, apart from that I don't get the "special" countries appearing again below in the listing of all countries.

Comment: Best answer, but should be `.order_by('-special')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, so you may give it a try, but it may not give it what you want...

in your view do this:

```
specials = Country.objects.filter(special=True)
all_of = Country.objects.all()

# worst thing is, this is a list, not a queryset...
new_list = list(specials)+list(all_of)

# add new object to you form...
YourForm.base_fields['contact_country'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x.id,x) for x in new_list])
```

Your handicap is, yo create the list using a list, not directly from queryset

This will solve your pronblem, with a dirty looking way, but it is a solution i used when modelform can not help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default [ordering](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering):

```
class Meta:
    ordering = [ '-special', 'printable_name' ]
```

You can also write a [custom manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) but it doesn't worth...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, but with a Currency list and spent an inordinate amount of time diving into overwriting the ModelChoiceField and the iterator. Eventually I found a much simpler solution using the TypedChoiceField, and coercing the selected list item into the appropriate model instance. This allowed for the cleaned value to be validated as the appropriate model type for the related field.

Create and provide your custom list of Country tuples as the choices, with your special countries at top, followed by all your countries including the special ones. Ex [(1,'US'),(2,'Canada'),(3,'Albania'),(4,'Botswana'),(2,'Canada'),(1,'US')] and so on.  It would be so much easier if you could append to a queryset, as opposed to union, or use a raw query.

```
contact_country = forms.TypedChoiceField(
    required=False,
    choices=custom_country_list_of_tuples,
    coerce=lambda pk: Country.objects.get(pk=pk),
    empty_value=None,
)
```

Hopefully, despite this question being more than 10 years old this solution will help save someone else a bunch of time. Though learning about overwriting the field models and iterators was interesting.